# How to make a search bar equal to the Windows file explorer in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a file explorer in vb.net and I put a TextBox and a button that for when I type something in the TextBox it looks for the name of documents, images or any other file that has the same name that I typed or if it has not it takes the most similar names, or no case has any files with the name typed or similar, EXACTLY AS THE FILE EXPLORER WINDOWS HAS.
(If you have how the TextBox fetches without needing a button is better still for me)
I already have a part of this project, but what is missing now is just that for now. I already have a sample path that when I start my file explorer it already takes a start path that I set and when it starts it already opens with the path "C: \ Program Files" and it is from that path that, when I type a name in the TextBox it looks for all documents, images or any other file that has the same name that I typed if it has, and also searches the subfolders if there is any file inside with the name that I typed.

The images from the examples below to show in more detail what I want.

[Windows explorer demo pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VqfY.jpg)

Windows file explorer demo gif: https://j.gifs.com/ROL4Xw.gif

[The design of my file explorer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDzZJ.jpg)

No need to show the path in which the file is as shown in this image: [Image of the path to the file that does not need to be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MpiV.jpg)

All my project code:

```
    Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim path As String
    Dim nextPath As String
    Public Property ListView1 As Object

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        On Error Resume Next
        path = TextBox1.Text
        If (My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(path)) Then

            explorer.Clear()

            For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
                explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 2)

            Next
            For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
                explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 1)
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox("Its A File")
            'or user
            'pocess.Start(path) // to open the file
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            path = "C:\Program Files"
            For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
                explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 2)

            Next
            For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
                explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 1)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("...")
            Application.Exit()
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles explorer.ItemSelectionChanged
        nextPath = path + "\" + e.Item.Text

    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles explorer.MouseDoubleClick

        Try

            If (My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(nextPath)) Then
                path = nextPath
                explorer.Clear()
                TextBox1.Text = path
                For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
                    explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 2)

                Next
                For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
                    explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 1)
                Next
            Else

                Process.Start(path & "\" & explorer.SelectedItems(0).Text)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("...")
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click

        Try
            nextPath = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("\"))
            path = nextPath
            explorer.Clear()
            TextBox1.Text = path
            For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
                explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 2)

            Next
            For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
                explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 1)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("...")
            Application.Restart()


        End Try

    End Sub



    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

I am sending the whole project if you want to test your machine for the best resolution of this problem: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArgT_dApPP30jZMh6yyaBtIck40PFg?e=afhOng

In the image that I sent  is marked in red TextBox2 and the button2 that is declared in the code below.

In the image that I sent "[The design of my file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vHWb.jpg)" is marked in red, TextBox2 and button2 that is declared in the code below.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    End Sub
```

Remember that if you have how to do the search using only the TextBox without needing a button is the best for me.

Comment: Yes, put code in the TextChanged event.  Or put the code in the Button2.Click event and have the TextChanged event call the `Button2_Click(Button2, EventArgs.Empty)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use [IExplorerBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iexplorerbrowser)  + [ISearchFolderItemFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-isearchfolderitemfactory)

The result will be the same as Explorer.

Test in VB.NET with P/Invoke :

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my delay. I have no idea how to do this. I've sent the whole project to you so that you can leave it to me because I do not know how to do it. I know I'm asking for a lot and thank you very much even for helping me.
But I do not know how to do this, if you ask me to put a code there and test I can, but if you ask me to search for something I can not because I have tried and do not understand much of this language.

Comment: Can send me your project (Test IExplorerBrowser & Search) of your example that sent in the image in gif, for me to see which command you use?

Comment: I uploaded the VB Test project (VS 2015) :  [VB_ExplorerBrowser_Search](https://app.box.com/s/3cb68nui7zojbrkwoq61d5zvlczozis6)

Comment: Thanks, I'm watching the max here to see if it helps me but I think it will not, but I already thank you very much for the help.